# extracting domain names(hostnames) out of a text file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sort, cut

i wanted to extract domain name(hostname)  with Connection timed out with top 5 delay time .

input file

```
Mar 19 21:44:00 ip-172-2-0-53 sendmail[30686]: v2K4g0Dm030684: to=<rdunia@jehdns.com>, delay=00:02:12, xdelay=00:02:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120847, relay=webmail.jehdns.com. [192.168.1.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with webmail.jehdns.com.
Mar 19 20:35:00 ip-172-2-0-54 sendmail[30683]: v2K4g0Dm030684: to=<esds@karna.com>, delay=00:02:00, xdelay=00:02:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120847, relay=webmail.jehdns.com. [192.168.1.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with webmail.karna.com.
Mar 21 23:15:20 ip-172-2-0-53 sendmail[7742]: v2M6FKZm007741: to=<root@prod-radion.ifad.internal>, ctladdr=<root@prod-radion.ifad.internal> (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=31116, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

Expected Output:

```
Mar 19 21 delay=00:02:12 - webmail.jehdns.com.
Mar 20 13 delay=00:02:00 - webmail.karna.com.
```

Comment: Well, do you have some command / script / something you have tried or are you just looking for the basics?

Comment: awk -F : '{ print $1,$10 }' maillog.txt | sort -u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -n '/timed out/{s/^\([^:]*\):.*xdelay=\([^,]*\),.*with \(.*\)$/\1 delay=\2 - \3/;p;}'
```

Comment: Working fine how can i get uniq domain in result

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F: -lane '
   ($i) = grep { $F[$_] =~ /delay=/ } 0 .. $#F;
   $d = join ":", join($\, @F[$i..$i+2]) =~ /\hdelay=\K\d+|\n\K\d+/g;
   print "$d:$F[0]", " delay=$d", " - ", /\S+$/g if $F[-1] =~ /timed out/;
' input_file |
 sort -t: -nr -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 | cut -d: -f4-
```

## Output

```
Mar 19 21 delay=00:02:12 - webmail.jehdns.com.
Mar 19 20 delay=00:02:00 - webmail.karna.com.
```